# Python C module function argument reference counting

Tags: python, c, python-module, python-c-api, cpython

When I have a `PyObject *` obtained from `PyArg_ParseTuple`, do I need to make sure to `Py_DECREF` it before I return from the function?

Example:

```
static PyObject * modulefunc(PyObject * self, PyObject * args) {
    PyObject * obj;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &obj)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, expected_type_ptr)) {
        // Do I need to Py_DECREF(obj) here?
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "First argument is not expected type.");
        return NULL;
    }

    // ... rest of function implementation.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. PyArg_ParseTuple gives you a [borrowed reference](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#extracting-parameters-in-extension-functions).